# Linux brightness script incrementing on sigmoid gradient

Tags: linux, bash, math, xorg, sigmoid

I have a little script for brightness on my Linux machine. Currently it in(de)creases a fixed amount when the bound key is pressed. How would I make this increase less and less as I approach the maximum brightness, and visa versa? The more minimal the better :)

```sh
#!/bin/sh


dir="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"

# echo $(( 750 +375 )) > "$dir/brightness"
bright () {
        echo $(($(cat "$dir/brightness") $1 )) > "$dir/brightness"
}

case $1 in
        "") echo "Screen: $(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)" ;;
        +) bright +375 ;;
        -) bright -375 ;;
        +*) bright $1 ;;
        -*) bright $1 ;;
        =)  echo "No value to set passed (0-7500)"  ;; # My machine specific
        =*) echo $1 | sed s/=// > "$dir/brightness" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Read the current value and change it depending on it.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of having a list of values, like: ``[0, 1, 2, 4, 9, 14, 16, 17, 18]``;  Then setting the brightness to the value one above/below the item with the same value's index but that seems crude, and difficult to implement in bash. I am looking for help with the implementation

Comment: Every time you press the key the Bash script is called. Every variable you set in the script is lost at the end of the script. To change the value the next value in the list you have to know the current value. So the first step is to read the current value.

Comment: Aren't I already doing that in the function? I may be misunderstanding, but getting the current value was never a problem I believe. The value of my screen brightness is in the ``/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`` file

Comment: You can start with two cases. If the current value is larger than a threshold add `375` and `200` otherwise. If this works you can extend it.